# Sorting LinkedList by student ID

Tags: java, sorting, linked-list

I am still a pretty novice programmer so please be as descriptive as possible. I'm having issues getting all my code working for my assignment. The assignment gives me four complete files that do not need changed (StudentIf.java, StudentCollectionIf.java, StudentLLNode.java and StudentRecords.java) and a test text file with a list of names an ID and five grades.

Link to Assignment Instructions: https://www.cs.colostate.edu/~cs161/Fall14/more_assignments/P5/P5.html

The two files that I have modified are Student.java and StudentLL.java. Also in my Run Configuration-Arguments I have "cs161 5". I know its a lot but any help would be fantastic.

I know the insort method is not really clean code at all but I couldn't get anything to work.

I am currently getting the right outputs but they are not sorted.

```
Top Score: 0.0
Avg Score: 0.0
Course: cs161
Adam    2143  85 95 85 75 65    score: 81.00
John    1243  60 70 80 55 55    score: 64.00
Mick    1324  70 60 70 80 90    score: 74.00
Ellen   2341  90 95 88 77 66    score: 83.20
Jim     1234  50 40 50 60 70    score: 54.00
Lena    1423  99 50 90 90 85    score: 82.80
Leila   1432  60 70 60 70 60    score: 64.00
Mike    1342  60 70 80 90 99    score: 79.80
Ada     2134  90 90 90 90 90    score: 90.00
Helen   2314  89 79 99 89 88    score: 88.80
```

Code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.TreeMap;

public class StudentLL implements StudentCollectionIF{
    private String course;
    private StudentLLNode head;
    private int size;
    private boolean debug;  // you can set debug in main

    // the client code provides the course name
    public StudentLL(String course){
        this.course = course;
    }

    public String toString(){
        String res = "Course: " + course + "\n";
        for(StudentLLNode curr = head; curr !=null; curr=curr.getNext()){
             StudentIF nS = curr.getStd();
             res = res + nS + "\n";
        }
        return res;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean insort(StudentIF s) {
        StudentLLNode curr = head;

        if (s == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (head == null) {
            StudentLLNode student = new StudentLLNode(s);
            head = student;
            size++;
            //System.out.println("working");
            return true;
        } else {
            if (curr.getStd().compareTo(s) == 0) {
                return false;
            }

            Map<Integer, StudentLLNode> tcur = new TreeMap<Integer, StudentLLNode>();
            tcur.put(curr.getStd().getId(), curr);
            while (curr.getNext() != null) {
                curr = curr.getNext();
                if(curr.getStd().compareTo(s) == 0) {
                    return false;
                }
                tcur.put(curr.getStd().getId(), curr);
            }
            curr.setNext(new StudentLLNode(s));
            tcur.put(curr.getStd().getId(), curr.getNext());
            System.out.println(s.getName() + " " + s.getId());
            ArrayList<StudentLLNode> bs = new ArrayList<StudentLLNode>();
            Iterator it = tcur.entrySet().iterator();
            while(it.hasNext()) {
                Map.Entry pairs = (Map.Entry)it.next();
                StudentLLNode sss = (StudentLLNode) pairs.getValue();
                bs.add(sss);
                it.remove();
            }

            for(int i = 0; i < bs.size(); i++) {
                //bs.get(i).setNext(bs.get(i + 1));
                if(i == bs.size() - 1) {
                    //bs.get(i).setNext(null);
                } else {
                    //bs.get(i).setNext(bs.get(i + 1));
                }
                System.out.println("\t" + bs.get(i).toString() + " NET " + bs.get(i).getNext() );
            }

            //bs.get(bs.size() - 1).setNext(null);
            //confused here
            /*StudentLLNode student1 = new StudentLLNode(s);
            curr.setNext(student1);*/
            size++;
            return true;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean remove(StudentIF s) {
        StudentLLNode current = head;
        if(s == null){
            return false;
        }
        if(s.equals(current.getStd())){
            //StudentLLNode  top = head;
            head = head.getNext();
            size--;
            return true;
        }
        else{
            StudentLLNode previous, next;
            previous = current;
            current = current.getNext();
            while(current != null){
               next = current.getNext();
               if(s.getId() == (current.getStd().getId())){  
                    previous.setNext(next);
                    size--;
                    return true;
                }
               previous = current;
               current = next;
            }
        }
        return false;
      }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return size;
    }

    @Override
    public double classAvg() {
//      int count = 0, total = 0;
//      for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++)
//      {
//          total += computeScore((StudentLLNode) head);
//          count++;
//      }
//      gettop();
//      return total / count;
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public double classTopScore() {
        return 0;
    }
    }
```

========

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Student implements StudentIF{

    private String name;
    private int id;
    private int[] grades;
    private int numGrades;
    private int totalGrades;

    // The constructor
    //    initializes the instance variables  
    //    name, id, grades = new int[totalGrades], and numGrades = 0;
    public Student (String name, int id, int totalGrades){
        this.name = name;
        this.id = id;
        grades = new int[totalGrades];
        this.totalGrades = totalGrades;
        numGrades= 0;

       //System.out.println(name+"  "+id+"   "+grades[0]+" "+grades[1]+" "+grades[2]+" "+grades[3]+" "+grades[4]+" "+"   "+totalGrades);
    }

    public String toString() {
        String res = name + "\t" + id + " ";
        for (int i=0; i < totalGrades; i++) {
            res += " " + grades[i];
        }
        res += "\tscore: " + new DecimalFormat("0.00").format(computeScore());
        return res;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(StudentIF arg0) {
        if (arg0 == null || arg0.getId() != id) {
            return 1;
        }

        /*if (this.id > arg0.getId())
            return 1;
        else if (this.id < arg0.getId())
            return -1;*/
        /*else {
            return 0;
        }*/

        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    @Override
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    @Override
    public double computeScore() {
        double total = 0;
          if (numGrades == 0) {
            return total;
          }
          if (numGrades > grades.length) {
            numGrades = grades.length;
          }
          for (int i = 0; i < numGrades; i++) {
            total += grades[i];
          }
          return total / grades.length;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean addGrade(int newGrade) {
        if(numGrades<grades.length){
            grades[numGrades] = newGrade;
            numGrades++;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean equals(StudentIF other) {
        if (other == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (this.id == other.getId()) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

}
```

Comment: Please do not copy all your code in here, be specific.

Comment: In order to custom sort the list use a Comparator or Comparable interface

Answer (score 0):

Make your Student class implement the `Comparable` interface and override the `compareTo` method

```
Class Student implements Comparable<Student>
{
private int id;

@Override
public int compareTo(Student s) {

    if (this.id > s.id)
        return 1;
    else if (this.id < s.id)
        return -1;
    else
        return 0;
}

}
```

Then by using `Collections.sort(yourlisthere)` you will get the list sorted according to Student `id`

Answer (score 0):

To expand a bit on @Abishek 's answer (and because I don't haven enough rep to comment), the compareTo method could be simplified to just

```
public int compareTo(Student s) {
    return this.id - s.id;
 }
```

You don't need to return specifically 1, -1, or 0 as you might infer from that answer. Just a positive number if this.id is "greater" than s.id, negative number if vice versa, or 0 if they're equal.